# CakePHP: changing link to 'tags/index/php' to just 'tags/php'

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I have a controller called TagsController that takes the tag name from the url in the index action to get a list of projects with that tag.

```
 <?php
foreach($tags as $tag){
    echo "<span class='homepagetags'>".$html->link($tag['t']['tag'], array('controller' => 'tags', $tag['t']['tag'])) . "</span> x " . $tag[0]['NumOccurrances'] . "<br><br>";
}
 ?>
```

the link takes me to 'tags/index/php' when I really just want it to be 'tags/php'

Is this a routing solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically, you need:

```
// routes.php
Router::connect(
   '/tags/:tag',
   array('controller' => 'tags', 'action' => 'index')
);
```

Then to create a link:

```
echo $html->link(
    'PHP Tag',
    array('controller' => 'tags', 'action' => 'index', 'tag' => 'php')
);
```

Comment: this is brilliant but the only problem now is my tag controller is giving me and error with function index($tag){
  
 } error is 'Missing argument 1 for TagsController::index()' when i remove the parameter from the action the error disappears

Comment: to answer my question above:  $tag = mysql_real_escape_string($this->params['tag']);

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a routing solution. It is explained about half way down the [Defining Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration#Defining-Routes-948) section in the Cookbook. The example is:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:controller/:id',
    array('action' => 'view'),
    array('id' => '[0-9]+')
);
```